# React hooks - how to test multiple useState hooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I have a component that has few useState hooks:

```
const [resizing, setResizing] = React.useState(false);
const [x, setX] = React.useState(0);
const [y, setY] = React.useState(0);
```

And in some places I am calling more than one hook at a time, for example here in `onResize`, I am calling both `setResizing` and `setX` or `setY` hook:

```
<ResizableBox
    height={520}
    width={370}
    minConstraints={[370, 520]}
    maxConstraints={[Infinity, Infinity]}
    className={classes.resizable}
    onResize={(e) => {
      if (e.movementX !== 0) {
        setResizing(true);
        setX((prev) => prev + e.movementX);
      } else if (e.movementY !== 0) {
        setResizing(true);
        setY((prev) => prev + e.movementY / 2);
      }
    }}
    onResizeStop={() => {
      setResizing(false);
    }}
  >
```

I am used to testing class components where it is easy to test state changes.

I would like to test it with something like this:

```
const setXSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'setX');
const setYSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'setY');
const setResizeSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'setResize');


it('calls useState hooks correctly', () => {
  resizableBox.props.onResize({movementX: 1});

  expect(setXSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
  expect(setYSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(setResizeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```

But, I am not sure how test hooks like that in this example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692521/how-to-mock-the-usestate-hook-implementation-so-that-it-actually-changes-the-sta/57692649#57692649

Comment: What react testing library do you use?

Comment: Just jest and react-test-renderer

Comment: You can use library such as Enzyme to do that, but its anti-pattern, usually you would want to  check state of UI component based on new state.

Comment: here is my solution i think that will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70709100/11769900

Answer (score 3):

You're testing the implementation details of that component which is not a good idea (you're basically coupling the test to that implementation, instead of using the test to determine that the component does what it is supposed to do).

Instead I would try and find a way to test the component as a user would and determine that the output is correct.

Start by integrating [testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) and then follow some of the patterns described [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-test-react-components-that-use-react-hooks) and [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library).

The question is, what are you trying to test? what is the expected outcome of this test and which behaviour will it cover?

LE: in your case, as I see you're trying to test React-Resizable, you can try and `mouseDown` on the resize handle, then emit `mouseMove` and `mouseUp` and see if the right things happens (I don't see from the code what you are doing with the state values, what are you using them for)

Answer (score 0):

The code I use to do that is the following:

```
const mockSetState = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react'),
  useState: () => ['', mockSetState],
}));


it('...', () => {
    expect(mockSetState).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, first expected value);
    expect(mockSetState).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, second expected value');
})
```